# On installing drush on my drupal site the drush will showing the the error

Tags: drupal-8

Drush 7.4.0 does not support Drupal 8. You will need Drush version 8 or higher. See http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/ for details.

Comment: The message says you'll need Drush 8 or higher if you're using Drupal 8. That means your version of Drush (7.4.0) is too old for your version of Drupal (8).

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest using composer to manage your Drupal site.
This will help you manage all the dependencies and tools needed by Drupal.

For drush you could do:
composer require drush/drush and it will select the latest version that will work with the version of your drupal site.

https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project